# how to call curl web services in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, json, web-services

how to call curl web services in ios, i want to call Curl web services in my iOS app which will return in JSON format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what effort have you made?

Comment: i already used simple web services in iOS, and i am new with Curl web services so now i want to know how can i call and get the result from the curl web service.

Comment: please elaborate more. curl is an http client.

Comment: i can call in my terminal and it's works fine but if i want to call in my browser it's showing error any other way where i can call in my browser. is it possible to call in my browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl is just an mechanism to make HTTP requests.  You do not need to use curl.  Instead just use a generic iOS HTTP request.  Sample Code:

```
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someurlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0f];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
if ( parameters ) {
    [request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:somejsondata options:0 error:nil]];
}

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if(error) {
    return error;
}
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
return json;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to use curl for login. For calling any other curl you can use this. Its working perfectly for me.

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:///xyz/login/"];

```
     NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

     [req setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

     NSString *boundary = @"0x0hHai1CanHazB0undar135";
```

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;   boundary=%@",boundary];

```
    [req addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // username

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",usernameField.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // password

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",passwordField.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set request body
    [req setHTTPBody:body];
```

NSError *error = nil;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];

Comment: This is just an http request... it is not a curl at all and the appends are much more difficult then just serializing json.